# Running separate perf record for separate processes parallely

Tags: c++, linux, perf

I want to parallely run perf record for separate processes, so that I can generate profiling data and analyse individually. However on runing two `perf record -F 99 -g -o <executable_name>.data -- <executable with args>` parallely I am receiving a `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error' what(): Device or resource busy` error.

I have ensured there is no issue with the processes running in parallel and I am also writing the perf outputs to separate files with `-o option`.

How can I run the two perf record parrallely?

EDIT : Perf Version 4.18.0-348.7.1.el8_5.x86_64

Comment: On what hardware, and what perf version?

Comment: Added them in the question

Comment: So some x86-64 CPU, but you didn't say which.  Like i7-6700k?  Like an AMD Zen 3?  A low-power CPU like Tremont?  Any of those might have very different performance counter hardware.

Comment: Are you running this on the same executable in the same directory, so they'd be trying to use the same `.data` file at the same time?  I wouldn't be surprised if `perf record` locks that

Comment: Are your processes doing any kind of I/O on a file or device?

Comment: @PeterCordes Its an AMD Ryzen Threadripper system, so it most probably isn't a low power CPU. Also I am running this with separate executables, albeit in the same directory. Hence the names of the `.data` files are also different. Hence I dont believe it could be an issue with file lock.

Comment: @kiner_shah Yes they are using I/O, but wouldn't each process acquire lock on the file while it is using it and hence lead to no issues? Also as I mentioned in the question, the processes are running without errors in parallel when not under perf , so I believe that rules out any issue due to I/O by the processes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is trying to lock too much memory.  Running one of them as root worked for me, but there are better ways like raising the `ulimit -l` mlock limit.

---

I tried it on my own system (kernel/perf version 5.16).  It fails with

```
Permission error mapping pages.
Consider increasing /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_mlock_kb,
or try again with a smaller value of -m/--mmap_pages.
(current value: 4294967295,0)
```

Presumably older versions of `perf` had less useful error messages.  IDK what the "current value" output is about, though: `cat /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_mlock_kb` says it's `516`.  Perhaps it's just a `-1` meaning unlimited, take max size from other settings.

516 is slightly more than half my `ulimit -l` of 1024 (max locked memory           in kbytes).

Unfortunately `perf record --mmap_pages $((400/4))` rounds up to 128 pages (512 KiB); that might be a minimum or something.  2x 512 is 1024, but it still doesn't work with that.  Perhaps I have something else running with a locked page.

Like some other settings, `ulimit -l` is per-user, across processes, so raising it should work.

I didn't investigate changing `/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_mlock_kb`.

Comment: Why would perf be trying to lock so much memory? Considering that I might have to run multiple such `perf record` (4 or more) in parallel, would it have a negative performance effect?

Comment: @Archismanpathak: I assumed it was for buffers written by interrupt handlers.  Or to make sure it doesn't lose samples by making sure it has somewhere to put them that's not going to block on a hard page fault.  512K is a pretty trivial amount of memory on a machine with multiple GiB, and for occasional profiling, also pretty minor even on an embedded system with 128 MiB or whatever.  The mlock limits are set very low because some systems have *many* users, and letting each of them lock more than 1 MiB would start to add up.

Comment: Actually in my system the max locked memory is 16777216 kilo bytes. I dont know but I think that should be enough.